# [promethues, rails]How to enable promethues on rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monitoring, prometheus

I have a live rails application and I am trying install the [prometheus monitoring service](http://prometheus.io/), using its [Ruby Client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby).

I ran the tutorials on the server and it worked well, but after a hours the **merics url** died.

How can I get it working on my live server?

If I add an existing project, such as is seen below, Prometheus gives a "not found" error

```
I, [2015-08-31T10:54:40.274066 #3542]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
/PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- prometheus/client/rack/collector (LoadError)
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from config.ru:8:in `block in <main>'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:768:in `call'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:768:in `build_app!'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `init_worker_process'
    from PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:655:in `worker_loop'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:529:in `spawn_missing_workers'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:540:in `maintain_worker_count'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.9.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /PATH/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

I have two servers

1. promethus_server
2. live_server + prometheus client)

The live_server and promethus_client are in different paths.

I run the promethus client manually  on the server :

```
$ rails new client
$ bundle (adding promethus-client Gem)
$ vi config.ru (add promethus lib)
$ rail s --binding=IP
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you install the gem to that server?

Comment: Here's what my config.ru looks like for a recent app I upgraded:
    require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
    require 'rack'
    require 'prometheus/client/rack/collector'
    require 'prometheus/client/rack/exporter'
    use Prometheus::Client::Rack::Collector
    use Prometheus::Client::Rack::Exporter
    run Rails.application

Comment: @Dan I add gem and change config file using your config files. THX :)

Comment: You're welcome. I went ahead and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what my `config.ru` looks like for a recent app I upgraded:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', FILE)
require 'rack'
require 'prometheus/client/rack/collector'
require 'prometheus/client/rack/exporter'

use Prometheus::Client::Rack::Collector
use Prometheus::Client::Rack::Exporter

run Rails.application
```